# Why HTML canvas collision is not happening for the ball and the paddle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am building my ping pong game with javascript, Canvas and HTML So here is my Javascript code below to create the paddle and the ball. I want to know how to make the collision happen between paddle and ball. Below are my javascript and HTML

Below is my HTML code. Here I am declaring the canvas element

```js
var c = document.getElementById("frame");

c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.31;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.55;

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var rx = 10;
var ry = 400;
var height = 70;
var width = 12;
var radius = 10;
var vx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);

function drawPad(rx, ry, height, width) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f2a34b";
    ctx.fillRect(rx, ry, height, width);
}

function drawCircle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();


}

function moveCircle() {

    requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle);

    if ((x + radius > 500) || (x - radius < 0)) {
        vx = 0 - vx;
    }



    if ((y + radius > 420) || (y - radius < 0)) {
        vy = 0 - vy;
    }

    x = x + vx;
    y = y + vy;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);
    drawCircle();
}

moveCircle();


window.onkeydown = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37 && rx > 20) {
        rx = rx - 20;

    } else if (event.keyCode == 39 && rx <= 420) {
        rx = rx + 20;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          canvas {
              border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
              background-color: rgb(175, 166, 166);
          }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <canvas id="frame"></canvas>
      <script src="canvas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see you verify the collision with the borders in your code, but not with the paddle itself.

You just need to add some condition to detect its collision with the paddle. If a collision happened then the ball will move up otherwise it moves down

```
if(y+radius>=ry)
    {
      moveUp = true;
      moveDown = false;
    }
    if(y+radius<=0)
    {
      moveUp = false;
      moveDown = true;
    }
```

and later tell the programe how it will happen

```
if(moveUp){
      //x = x + vx;
      y = y - vy;
    }
    if(moveDown){
      //x = x - vx;
      y = y + vy;
    }
```

which gives you something like that if i am not mistaken :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("frame");

c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.31;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.55;

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var rx = 10;
var ry = (window.innerHeight*0.55)-10;
var height = 70;
var width = 12;
var radius = 10;
var vx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
let moveUp = false;
let moveDown = true;

drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);

function drawPad(rx, ry, height, width) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f2a34b";
    ctx.fillRect(rx, ry, height, width);
}

function drawCircle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();


}

function moveCircle() {

    requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle);

    /*if ((x + radius > 500) || (x - radius < 0)) {
        vx = 0 - vx;
    }*/

    if((x+radius>=rx)&&(y+radius>=ry))
    {
      moveUp = true;
      moveDown = false;
    }
    if(y+radius<=0)
    {
      moveUp = false;
      moveDown = true;
    }

    /*if ((y + radius > 420) || (y - radius < 0)) {
        vy = 0 - vy;
    }*/

    if(moveUp){
      //x = x + vx;
      y = y - vy;
    }
    if(moveDown){
      //x = x - vx;
      y = y + vy;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);
    drawCircle();
}

moveCircle();


window.onkeydown = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 37 && rx > 20) {
        rx = rx - 20;

    } else if (event.keyCode == 39 && rx <= 420) {
        rx = rx + 20;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    drawPad(rx, ry, height, width);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          canvas {
              border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
              background-color: rgb(175, 166, 166);
          }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <canvas id="frame"></canvas>
      <script src="canvas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```